# Modify keystore organization field

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore

I do have access to .jks as well as password of keystore and alias password. Now the organization name changed and I need to change it in keystore alias as well, as some stores list that information as well.. Is that possible to do without creating new alias and loosing app in playstore which is released long time ago?

Comment: No you cant change the Organization name later once you uploaded the apk.

Answer (score 0):

As [Maulik Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4657495/maulik-patel) pointed out in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920269/modify-keystore-organization-field#comment88712844_49920269), it is not possible to change the organization after the APK file was uploaded to Google Play.